# 'teamview' object has no attribute 'get_object'

Tags: python, django, django-views, mixins

I have a problem with UserPassesTestMixin, I want to restrict views from viewing people assigned for the manager. It's giving me an error of 'teamview' object has no attribute 'get_object'.

Here is my views.py in question:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, DetailView
from .models import Job, Member
from profiles.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.


class jobs(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'users/user_jobs.html'
    context_object_name = 'jobs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.filter(member__member=self.request.user)


class createdjobs(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'users/manager_jobs.html'
    context_object_name = 'jobs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.filter(manager__manager=self.request.user)


class teamview(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,ListView):
    model = Member
    template_name = 'users/manage_team.html'
    context_object_name = 'members'


    def test_func(self):
        return self.get_object().manager == self.request.user

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Member.objects.filter(manager__manager=self.request.user)



class jobdetail(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Job


class createjob (LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,CreateView):
    model = Job
    fields = ['member','title', 'description', 'file']

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.manager=manager.objects.get(manager=self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        return self.get_object().manager == self.request.user
```

Hope you cna help me out with this TIA.

Answer (score 0):

In your `class teamview(..., ..., ListView)` you are inheriting `ListView`. A `ListView` does not have `get_object()`, since there is more than one object. Here is a site which is great for checking all the available methods in class views: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

Side Note: I would recommend looking into [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and installing a linter in your editor to follow best practices. This will help other developers read your code.

Comment: What should be a good substitute? Queryset works but it doesnt't work when I did the test_func....

Comment: Is it .getobjects?

Comment: I mean self.objects?

Comment: The solution depends on what you trying to do with ```def test_func(self):
        return self.get_object().manager == self.request.user```?

Comment: What I'm trying to get out of it is to check first if the user is under the manager model or an instance of it. The listview teamview is only restricted for users under the manager category.